# Update SQL Server table with multiple values using set

Tags: sql, sql-server

How to update multiple values in a SQL server table? Here are the values in the table for the column X:
80, 81, 90
I want these to be updated to 0080, 0081, 0090

I have been updating each value this way:
update TBL_NAME
set TXN_ID = '0094'
where TXN_ID = '94'

I know the 'IN' operator didn't work. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This only makes sense if `X` is a string.  In that case, you can use:

```
update tbl_name
    set txn_id = right('0000' + txn_id, 4)
    where txn_id <> right('0000' + txn_id, 4);
```

If `x` is a number of any sort, you cannot prepend it with zeros.  You would have two options:

- Add a generated column that is a string padded with zeros.
- Convert the column to a string and then pad the value.

Comment: Thank you Gordon, yes x is a string. I'll keep this in mind for future reference. :)